# How to implement a "horizontal toggle responsive menu, where excess menuitems are combined into a dropdown"?

Tags: jquery, design-patterns, user-interface, menu, responsive-design

I'm trying to find some lead/information/implementation on a top toggle menu for a website that **selectively and progressively** moves low-priority menuitems into a submenu (eg. "more...") as it tries to adapt on narrower target screens.

The only **actual example** I've seen is the **Outlook.com** menubar (metro-styled): It uses this very effect; the menu displays only the items that fit in the window's width by moving all the excessive items into a submenu under the "..." menuitem.

I've come across is a very detailed description on the mozilla dev. network regarding this UI pattern where it's mentioned as a "**top toggle menu**" and it appears that some people also call this a "**Priority**"/"**Priority+**" menu. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Design/Responsive_Navigation_Patterns#Pattern_1.3A_Top_toggle_menu)

However not much information available. Anybody knowing a bit more about this? I doubt it's such a rare beast... Anybody knowing a more fit name, some article/thread or -ideally- some jQuery/javascript piece of code that can achieve this effect?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came across this question while looking for something similar and after a couple more hours of research found [this](https://github.com/352Media/flexMenu/) which might be a good start..